# As per usability which view is better to show product hierarchy: Horizontal view or Vertical view?

Tags: usability, hierarchy, categorization, product-design, view

I am facing problem to show complete hierarchy of consumer product for a company where products can be up to 500. And hierarchy can be up to 7 level. I am attaching 4 level horizontal & vertical hierarchy view, please vote for which one is better. You can also share other better option. Thanks!

[image: horizontal view of product hierarchy]

[image: vertical view of product hierarchy]

Comment: Before you decide how to display your hierachies you should reconsider the 7 levels. I think your hiearhcy is too deep and will be diffucult to use and understand. I suggest you to use a wide and shallow hierachy of maximum 3-4 levels.

Comment: Thanks @DesignerAnalyst !  But I can't change hierarchy levels because it's predefined by client. I can change only view of this hierarchy for easy & better access.

Comment: The client is not always right, information architecture is part of the UX, but maybe there is a business constraint that requires 7 levels.

Answer (score 1):

When u have a more than 4 level of hierarchy it becomes harder for user to see the hierarchy structure i.e Parent>child1>child2>child3>sibling1>sibling2>Child4 in this case you lose context of in which parent does the child exist or in which child does a sibling exist.
it is always good to use a lines that connects to each other with a indention and clearly shows the structure of a hierarchy.

Check my attached examples.
I have made a version using grey shades , each level has a different shade and this is upto 4 level and if hierarchy extends beyond that the last color will repeat (as too many shades spoils the design)

Hope this helps!!
Let me know if i can help you more

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure , But even if you are using horizontal approach try keeping context available for user. may be try to use a breadcrumbs and show their previous selections